# Read parameters using variables

Tags: batch-file, variables, parameters, arguments

I have a problem reading parameters that have been added to a subroutine. These parameters can of course be read in the following way.

```
call :test one two three

:test
    echo %1
    echo %2
    echo %3
exit /b
```

But I would like to read it in a loop as long as they are filled.

I made the following for that, but I don't get it working properly.
With my limited understanding of all this. I would normally request a variable on the 3 dots. So %p%.

```
call :test one two three

:test
    set /a p=1

    :while
    if [%...] NEQ [] (
        echo %...
        set /a p=p+1
    goto :while
    )
exit /b
```

Can someone tell me how I solve this?

Comment: You need the [shft](https://ss64.com/nt/shift.html) command.

Comment: or if it's just to echo the parameters line by line, all you need in the `:test` subroutine is `for %%a in (%*) do echo %%a` (where `%*` is a list of "all parameters")

Comment: This must be a duplicate question, but I am too burnt out to go and find one with a good answer.

Comment: You need to put `exit /B` after the `call` command line to not continue execution unintentionally...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Stephan. It works just like i want :

```
:test
for %%A in (%*) do (
    echo %%A
)
exit /b
```

Comment: Please accept the answer that solved your issue (even if it's your own) to remove this question from the "unanswered" queue.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
call :test one two three
call :test four five
call :test seven eight nine ten
CALL :test
goto :eof

:test
rem for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set parm 2^>nul') do set "%%a="
set /a parmcnt=0
:testlp
set /a parmcnt+=1
SET "parm%parmcnt%=%1"
SHIFT
IF DEFINED parm%parmcnt% GOTO testlp
SET /a parmcnt-=1
ECHO %parmcnt% parameters
IF %parmcnt% gtr 0 FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%parmcnt%) DO CALL ECHO %%parm%%a%%
ECHO -------------------
SET parm
ECHO ===================
GOTO :EOF
```

The meat here is the `:testlp` loop. The parameter count `parmcnt` is incremented, and the variable `parm...` is set to `%1` - the first parameter, then the paramter list is `SHIFT`ed which simply removes the first parameter from the apparent list.

if the `parm...` has a value, then try again, until all of the parameters have been assigned to parm*

decrement the parameter count (since the last assignment attempt assigned a value of *nothing* as `%1` did not exist) and display the results.

The result-display is in two parts. The first uses a parsing trick (to avoid `delayed expansion` which is a whole new ball-game). The parser first substitutes for the *metavariable* `%%a`, so what is executed is `call echo %%parm1%%` etc. for `1` to `%parmcnt%`. `call`ing the `echo` executes `echo %parm1%` in a subshell.

The second simply shows all variables `set` which start `parm`. Note that parm%parmcnt+1% will always be empty, but there may be stray `parm`s set from prior invocations of `:test`

Hence the remmed-out `for ... set parm` line which clears all variables starting `parm`. Removing the `rem` from this line would dispose of the stray variables problem, but note that it would also clear any variablename that starts `parm` - like `parmlimit` had `parmlimit` been set.

Comment: I like @stephan's `for %%a in (%*) do echo %%a` suggestion.  It's a simpler, more direct answer to the OP's question.